# using add_tooltip in ggvis to print name when mouse hovers

Tags: r, ggvis

My data looks something like this:

```
df = data.frame(name=c("A1", "A2"),
                x = c(2,4),
                y = c(2,5),
                sector = c("blue", "red"))
```

I am trying to use ggvis to create a graph but I am not able to make the tooltip work.

```
library(ggvis)
df %>% 
  ggvis(~x, ~y, size := 100, opacity := 0.4) %>% 
  layer_points(fill = ~sector) %>%
  add_tooltip(function(df) df$name)
```

When I hover the mouse `df$name` does not appear. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The helpfile for add_tooltip has a clue:

> The data sent from client to the server contains only the data columns
>   that are used in the plot. If you want to get other columns of data,
>   you should to use a key to line up the item from the plot with a row
>   in the data.

My fix below adapts the example from that helpfile.

```
library(ggvis)

df = data.frame(name=c("A1", "A2"),
                x = c(2,4),
                y = c(2,5),
                sector = c("blue", "red"))

# Add a unique id column
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)

# Define a tooltip function, which grabs the data from the original df, not the plot
tt <- function(x) {
   if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)

   # match the id from the plot to that in the original df
   row <- df[df$id == x$id, ]   
   return(row$name)
}


# in the definition of the plot we include a key, mapped to our id variable
df %>% 
   ggvis(~x, ~y, key := ~id, size := 100, opacity := 0.4) %>% 
   layer_points(fill = ~sector) %>%
   add_tooltip(tt, "hover")
```